# Injecting Map of customized objects in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I am new to Guice. I have written following module:

```
public class TransactionConfigModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {

    MapBinder<String, ITransactionManager> transactionModeMap = MapBinder
            .newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, ITransactionManager.class
            , Names.named("TransactionManagerMap"));

    transactionModeMap.addBinding(TransactionMode.CREDIT.platformName())
                           .to(CreditCardManager.class)
                           .asEagerSingleton();
  transactionModeMap.addBinding(TransactionMode.DEBIT.platformName())
                           .to(DebitCardManager.class)
                           .asEagerSingleton();
 }
}
```

And then I have created the injector (which has been there already) as follows:

```
  Injector injector = createInjector(
            new PaymentModule()
    );
```

PaymentModule (which has been already there) is like following:

```
   public class RBSAVSTechServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
     ...
     protected void configure(){
         install(new TransactionConfigModule()); <--- I just added this line in the existing code
     }
   }
```

Here I am getting following exception:

```
 No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ITransactionManager> was bound.
```

I am not getting any idea regarding how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

From the example above it is not clear where you are installing `RBSAVSTechServiceModule`. I assume it is done inside `PaymentModule`.
I also note that you created the map binder using a binding annotation. Are you sure that your injection point is using the corresponding `@Named("TransactionManagerMap")`? The error message seems to indicate it is not.